Getting Error: 429 Too Many Requests on a local validator instance
This question is different than this one or this one as they relate to mainnet.
Not sure what is causing it, few days ago I did not have this issue. I did not change my testing set-up, testing procedure or change any packages. Now this error it merely spams my logs, everything goes through otherwise but it is hard to read console.logs in my test files.
I'd love to be able to disable display of this error.
